# converting string to datetime using DateTimeConverter

Tags: c#-4.0, datetime-format

I want to convert a date in string format  into Datetime without spliting it.I tried 
but any of those not working properly.can I do this by using DateTimeConverter . I have no idea about DateTimeConverter

Comment: What does your date time string look like? Have you tried DateTime.Parse?

Comment: yes,It works in my machine without any problem,but when the app running in another machines it gives an exception

Comment: What exception? Its probably a cultural problem - have you checked if both machines have the same cultural settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2012/10/18")
```

2.

```
DateTimeFormatInfo dtFormat = new System.GlobalizationDateTimeFormatInfo();

dtFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy/MM/dd";

DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2012/10/18", dtFormat);
```

3.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2012/10/18", "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

or

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2012/10/18", "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

ps:
CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
string format = "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss zz00 yyyy";
string stringValue = DateTime.Now.ToString(format, cultureInfo);
DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact("Wed Aug 25 16:28:03 +0800 2010", format, cultureInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimeString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need DateTimeConverter. You can simply use the Datetime.Parse method.

```
string dateInString = "10/17/2012 12:06:30 PM";
var dt = DateTime.Parse(dateInString);
```

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I tried this but gives an error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"